# Update select list options on form submission

Tags: 7, forms

I have a views exposed form which is submitted through ajax.

I have two select list fields. `Selectlist Field 1` and `Selectlist Field 2`.

The form has been submitted on Selecting an option in `Selectlist Field 2`. So I want to remove some options of field `Selectlist Field 1` on this form submission.

I tried the following code.

```
    if (!empty($form_state['input']['Selectlist_Field_2'])) {
      foreach ($form_state['input']['Selectlist_Field_2'] as $value) {
        $nids = get_nids($value);
        foreach ($form['Selectlist_Field_1']['#options'] as $key => $value) {
          if(in_array($key, $nids)) {
            unset($form['Selectlist_Field_1']['#options'][$key]);
          }
       }
     }
  }
```

I write the above code in `form_alter`. But it did not update the `Selectlist Field 1` options in the form. I have print out the `Selectlist Field 1` options outside `foreach` and inside the `if` statement and it prints the updated options.

But don't know why the field is not update in the form on the site.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any other method?

Comment: Hi. Did you say you want to populate SelectList Field 1 with the values of SelectList Field 2 ? Maybe you sould find another function apart "unset". Because it seem to me that "unset" only means something like destroy or erase a value. But as I look into the code above, I do not see an instruction that writes into SelectList Field 1. Maybe I'm wrong but that what I see. Maybe that can help a bit.

Comment: Yeah I want to remove some options from the `Selectlist Field 1` field based on the values of `Selectlist Field 2` selection.

Comment: You say " So I want to remove some options of field Selectlist Field 1 on this form submission." do you mean when the ajax is called after Field 2 is selected? "on form submission" implies  the user has pressed submit... and can you add your ajax form element and callback?

Comment: When I select an option in Field 2, I submit the form by triggering the click event on submit button using javascript therefore the form has been submitted on selecting an option in Field 2. So based on its value I want to remove some options from Field 1.